# Graph build of triangles

Tags: graph-theory

Is there any name for a graph build only with triangles ?

I mean a graph, which is result of gluing vertices of many triangles ( not necessary gluing edges) including structures which are fan like.

Exaple: 3 simplex skeleton with 10 triangles glued to its edges ( with multiple edges in a places where gluing has place) .

Comment: A *triangulation*.

Comment: No. Triangulation require no multiplicity of edges. And triangulation, usually is embedable info manifold, whilst I am asking about more general situation where triangles may form book like construction.

Comment: No, because of multiple edges. I mean a graph, which is result of gluing vertices of many triangles ( not necessary gluing edges)

Comment: ok, it probably is. Could it has book- like structure? That is for example 10 triagles fan glued by one edge? Is it still triangulation ? Even it has no manifold embeddeing?

Comment: Yes $K_4$ is ok, even if you remove an edge. But I am afraid of book like structure ( a graph glued with triangles which is embedsble in n semi planes glued by a line)

Comment: I am just asking if it has any name in literature...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on Google+ one of friends of mine give an answer: Chordak graph --> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_graph and it looks pretty good...